# Disable Weekends

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I wish you could help block weekends with type date
I have type date:

input class="form-control" type="date" id="date1" min="2021-01-01" name="calendario"

Comment: Please provide a minimum (not-)working example.

Comment: so i go to my website i open my calendar and the weekends remain there unblocked

Answer (score 0):

This is not my code this is your answer by user: 1444609
code written by: user:1444609

```
const picker = document.getElementById('date1');
picker.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var day = new Date(this.value).getUTCDay();
  if([6,0].includes(day)){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = '';
    alert('Weekends not allowed');
  }
});
<input id="date1" size="60" type="date" format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" />
```

Comment: I've tried with this code but it doesn't work, thanks anyway